Does Spring Security try to authorize the customer for a public endpoint?
Assuming, that I have an endpoint that is accessible only to authenticated users,
now I want to grant access to non-authorized users as well.
Do I need to expect that Spring Security will try to authorize the user even when the user is trying to reach the public endpoint?
I mean, will I be able to determine who exactly is reaching the public endpoint - authorized or non-authorized user?

You can specifiy exactly who gets access granted, authorized, non-authorized, both, just a matter of configuration.


Do I need to expect that Spring Security will try to authorize the user even when the user is trying to reach the public endpoint?

No, Spring Security will not apply any authorization if you configured an endpoint with permitAll(). However, if there is any authentication mechanism configured, it will try to authenticate.
Consider the following configuration:
http
  .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
    .requestMatchers("/public").permitAll()
  )
  .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());


If you make a request to /public with the wrong basic credentials, the request will fail because the authentication failed, even if this is a public endpoint. On the other hand, if you provide valid credentials, Spring Security will authenticate the user but won't use it for authorization.

It's 100% based on the configuration you make for Spring Security, you can configure what endpoints can be accessed by what users.
Example :
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, UserAuthProvider userAuthProvider) throws Exception {

    http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthFilter(userAuthProvider), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement(customizer -> customizer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) ->
                    requests.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login", "/register").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated());
    return http.build();
}

In this case endpoints /login , /register are allowed for unauthorized users,
and all other endpoints require authentication.

I guess /login, /register endpoints are allowed for unauthorized and authorized users, aren't they?

Yeah in this case /login and /register endpoints are allowed for everyone , authorized and unauthorized

okay, then how can I know who is trying to connect to the /login endpoint?  because it can be an authorized or unauthorized user.

Checking the headers , most of the time when a user is authenticated a header with authentication type and some token is passed ;) to check that you also have to make a configuration and how you validate this token. I'd recommend reading
link

If you don't have to decide a specific behavior on whether authorized or not but rather protect endpoints from being hit by already authenticated users you can check for .hasRole("ANONYMOUS"), since this is the standard role Spring applies to unauthenticated users. You can customize predefined roles for users which aren't authenticated yet. And you can fine grain access additionally via Method Security at controller level.
